# “Poteach Et Yadecha” Before Hamotzie

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, hamotzi-beracha

It is a known Minhag among Sepharadim before Hamotzie to say the pasukim “Eyine Kol Elecha Yesaberu… Poteach Et Yadecha…”

I’m trying to hunt the original source for this minhag - the best I can find is in Shulchan Aruch (Kuf Samech Zayin) it states that you should place your hands on the bread (which have 10 fingers) which also correspond to the 10 words in The Bracha of Hamotzie and the 10 words in the Pasuk “ Eyine Kol Elecha…” - but I can’t find anywhere it states to explicitly say those words before Hamotzie. Is anyone aware of the original source for this Minhag?

> יתן שתי ידיו על הפת בשעת ברכה, שיש בהן י' אצבעות כנגד י' מצות התלויות בפת ולכך יש י' תיבות בברכת המוציא וי' תיבות בפסוק מצמיח חציר לבהמה (תהילים קד, יד) וי' תיבות בפסוק עיני כל אליך ישברו (תהילים קמה, טו) וי' תיבות בפסוק ארץ חטה ושעורה (דברים ח, ח) וי' תיבות בפסוק ויתן לך (בראשית כז, כח).

Comment: I am unaware of a source for saying it before hamotzie, but the אליה רבה סימן קס"ה סק"ד brings to say it before נטלית ידים.